# PayPal iOS SDK won't save payerID to PayPal backend

Tags: ios, paypal, sdk

I have the following code:

```
NSLog(@"Email address is %@",aPayerId);

PayPalPaymentViewController *paymentViewController;
paymentViewController = [[PayPalPaymentViewController alloc]
                            initWithClientId:kPayPalClientId receiverEmail:kPayPalReceiverEmail payerId:aPayerId payment:payment delegate:self
                         ];

[self presentViewController:paymentViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The email address prints out fine in the output window.  The payment and everything goes through, however the aPayerId data does not get saved.

Any suggestions.

Comment: Where should it be saved?

Comment: It should be saved in the PayPal dashboard in the table with the payments.